# JQuery plugin namespaces and iterators

Tags: jquery

I write this code:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        videoGallery: function() {

            this.each(function() {

                gallery = $(this); // present object in the $.each iteretor

                $(this).find('a').click(function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert( gallery.attr('id') );
                });             


            });                                     
        }
    });
})(jQuery);

$('.video-gallery').videoGallery();
```

Why, when I click on "a" element, the var gallery have always the same value and it's correspond to the last gallery in the `$.each` iteretor?

Thanks, and sorry for my English, it's not my natural language

Answer (score 0):

You missed the var keyword, try

```
...
var gallery = $(this);
```

maybe that's the issue.

Comment: @mauriblint Did that fix the problem? If so plz accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how closures work. The `gallery` variable is global (by mistake?) and you assign a new value on each iteration, so when any click event is triggered and the loop is done, the gallery is the last one in the loop. Try something like:

```
$(this).find('a').click((function(gallery) {
  return function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert( gallery.attr('id') );
  };
}(gallery)));
```

You can also use `var gallery = $(this)` to assign it to a local variable inside the loop closure.

Comment: Thanks! now, it's works perfectly!! Can i give karma here? I'm noob in this forum!